# ¿Cuál es el origen del uso de "patilla" en vez de "sandia" en Venezuela?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, venezuela

Hasta donde sé yo, todo el mundo hispanohablante llama al fruto *sandia* (en ingles "watermelon"), menos en Venezuela donde se le llama *patilla*.  Pero patilla tambien significa "sideburn" en inglés.

¿Por qué esta curiosidad regional?  No veo ninguna razón para conectar las dos palabras.  ¿Cómo se desarolló la "patilla" para denominar el fruto en Venezuela?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyp7xt-ygy0 Explica casi lo todo.

Comment: El video que @ZaneEdwardDockery enlaza es muy entretenido, es una canción que se burla de las diferencias regionales del español, pero no añade anda acerca del posible origen de `patilla` en Venezuela.

Comment: Y también (en Venezuela) le decimos patillas a las `bandas de pelo facial que se han dejado crecer a ambos lados de la cara de un hombre, junto a los oídos descendiendo por la mandíbula. (Wikipedia)`

Comment: @AxelA.García, concuerdo con usted. En Colombia también tienen el mismo significado, de hecho, si uno va  a comprar una `sandía`, uno también puede referirse a esta fruta como `sandía` y es perfectamente claro lo que se intenta decir. No conozco el origen del uso de estas palabras, pero [una pequeña búsqueda en Google Images puede ayudar al OP.](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=patilla&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivsa7ostHJAhWGwiYKHehdAiQQ_AUIBygB&biw=1366&bih=667)

Comment: En Puerto Rico también se le llama patilla ,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es curioso que a veces el origen de una palabra no lo sabemos ni los hablantes del idioma. No soy de Venezuela, pero he encontrado esto:

> A veces se llamó بَطِّيخَة سِنْدِيَّة *baṭṭīḫa sindiyya*, "melon del Sind", de donde salió el español *sandía*, como el catalán *[síndria](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0125079)*, *[xíndria](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0144491)* y el sardo [*sìndria*](http://sc.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ACndria), pero otras veces se llamaba بَطِّيخَة هِنْدِيَّة *baṭṭīḫa hindiyya* "melón de la India", o, incluso llegó a llamarse بَطِّيخَة فَلَسْطِينِيَّة *baṭṭīḫa falasṭīniyya* "melón de Palestina", pues se había cultivado antes en Palestina que en España. Otras veces, porque se distinguía como "verde" la sandía y "amarillo" el melón, se le llamó simplemente بَطِّيخَة *ba**ṭṭīḫ**a* "melón", sin adjetivo alguno, como hacen actualmente en el árabe de Oriente, donde el significado de "sandía" (*Citrullus lanatus* (Thunb.) Matsum. & Nakai) se ha adueñado completamente del fitónimo بَطِّيخَة *ba**ṭṭīḫ**a* y el melón tiene ahora que llamarse de otro modo, por ejemplo شَمَّام *šammām* que literalmente era "oloroso". De llamarla simplemente بَطِّيخَة *ba**ṭṭīḫ**ah* salió el nombre en español [*badea*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=badea), arabismo muy depreciado ("sandía o melón de mala calidad") y el **diminutivo بُطَّيْخَة *buṭṭayḫa*** dio también el español (depreciado) [*albudeca*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=albudeca), el portugués [*pateca*](http://www.infopedia.pt/lingua-portuguesa/pateca?homografia=2), el francés [*pastèque*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/past%C3%A8que) **y el español antillano de Colombia, Venezuela, Puerto Rico y Dominicana *patilla***  ([DLE acepción 6](http://dle.rae.es/?w=patilla)).

Fuente: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?sandi.a, con los enlaces actualizados.

Answer (score 2):

Es evidente el origen árabe. En el Quijote a la sandía se le llama "[badea](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4lTdcrU)", badea da "badía" y esta da "patilla".
Lo curioso que en partes de Venezuela y Colombia se conservó el nombre de badea para un fruto parecido externamente a la sandía y así se llama en la Cordillera oriental de Colombia y Andes de Venezuela badea a la *Passiflora quadrangularis*, llamada en Caracas "parcha granadina" y cuyo bejuco es cuadrado. Parcha es la palabra de origen caribeño con que se llama a todo tipo de pasiflora en Venezuela. J.Olza